# ScreenCloud Tray Icon Disappeared

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons, system-tray

Yesterday, after installing MythTV, I uninstalled it realizing that it's not what I was looking for. With it, MySQL server and a few other things installed, so I used Software Center's history to see what the other things were and remove them.

Later, after attempting to run Skype, I realize that it's not installed at all. ScreenCloud, too. After checking history, I see that they were both uninstalled at the same time. I am 100% positive I didn't do that. But I install them back.

Skype works perfectly but ScreenCloud's tray icon is missing. It's running and snapping when I press the button combo, but I can't change settings or do anything with it, there's no tray icon. If I end it in System Monitor and restart it, same results - running but no icon.

Anyone has an idea what's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScreenCloud dev here. I've seen this issue a few times before and it usually means that you're missing the libqt4-svg package. Installing it should fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-svg
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it alright. I've uninstalled it when I tried to uninstall the components installed by MythTV. Thanks a bunch!